# Can git automatically store the commit date in a file

Tags: git

I have a number of text files under git control. The files include a line of text such as this:

```
Date of this revision: 23.05.2021
```

Is it possible to make git update this automatically whenever the file is committed? I know it can be done in version control systems such as RCS, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it in git.

Comment: This information is kept in the commit itself. Why do you need it in another file?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because the file is displayed as a web file and users need to be able to see when the information was last updated.

Comment: What kind of users? Where is this information shown? Why are you not able to use the git commit date instead?

Comment: Users that view the file. It's HTML. Yes, I could write PHP code that extract the information from the git repository, but it would just be much easier if the information is simply there. Other version control systems provide this functionality, surely there must be a way to do it in git as well.

Comment: Doesn't the file's own "modified date" give that information?

Comment: Probably, but this still doesn't store the information in the file displayed to the user. Look, if it isn't possible to do this in git, just say so.

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to say it is or isn't possible in git. I'm thinking that it must be significantly easier to get the information from elsewhere.

Comment: How about a pre commit hook? No need to get frantic for heavens sake.

Comment: It seems to me that Gerrit is what you need since you said the file is displayed as a web file.

Comment: See "Keyword Expansion" at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a solution may be to write a **git client hook** by writing an **pre-commit** hook in order to:

1. Get the list of changed files.
2. Search for your header comments to update.
3. Stage again the updated file(s).
4. Return a success by the hook in order to perform the commit.

The nasty thing is that you have to create a template on each developer machine to initialize the repo with the hook(s) at each **git clone**.

Here https://www.omerkatz.com/blog/2013/5/23/git-hooks-part-2-implementing-git-hooks-using-python you can find a lot of information about writing and managing hooks.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it might be necessary to do this. I'm just surprised that this feature, which is frequently used in other version control systems, is not a basic part of git.

Comment: Changing a file's *content* to track its modification date get in the way of other very useful features, such as `merge`, `rebase` and content based hashing (central to git's storage). git stores this information *next* to the files (in the commit data, you can find the author, the commit's date ...)

Comment: @LeGEC: I think the trick (that other version control systems may or may not apply) is to consider the *static placeholder* the content when it comes to `merge`, `rebase` or content-based hashing. That is, the concrete file saved in a working copy might contain e.g. `$Date: 2023-02-10$` or `$Date: 2022-12-31` or anything else; from the VCS's point of view it the file is treated as if that character range were just `$Date$`.